# Patching Installing question

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, cumulative-update, patching

I usually install SP2013 CU every month. For some reason, I missed May and June. If I install July, do I get all the hotfixes and Security updated for missing May and June or install them as well?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CU are cumulative. It includes all the previous CUs and previous Security update. If you install the latest CUs then you are good as it will cover all previous updates as well.